# Is the identity a cofibration?

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

In a closed model category, is the identity $\textrm{id}: A \to A$ a cofibration? Does it only hold on some special cases? Or is it never true?

Comment: I'm only a casual user of model categories, but in many treatments of them (e.g. in Dwyer-Spalinski) it is explicitly part of the definition that all identity morphisms are simultaneously fibrations, cofibrations, and weak equivalences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: it is always a cofibration. Fix a trivial fibration $f : X \to Y$. It suffices to show that $\hom(A,X) \to \hom(A,Y) \times_{\hom(A,Y)} \hom(A,X)$ is surjective (informally: $\mathsf{id}$ lifts against $f$). Inspecting the codomain of this map, we see that it's isomorphic to $\hom(A,X)$ so the map is not only surjective, it's an isomorphism.

The same argument shows that any isomorphism is a cofibration and even---as weak equivalences contain all isomorphisms---a trivial cofibration. This argument also does not require the model category to be closed or satisfy any additional properties. One consequence is that this fact then dualizes to show that isomorphisms are also (trivial) fibrations.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. An isomorphism in a category has the left lifting property with respect to all morphisms. In a model category a morphism that has the LLP with respect to all trivial fibrations is a cofibration. Therefore every isomorphism is a cofibration.